# How does Google generate its OpenID claimed_id tokens?

Tags: django, openid, django-openid-auth

I'm using the `django_openid_auth` module and have it configured to automatically create new user accounts for new OpenIDs.  This makes the "sign up" process really trivial, but I'm a bit worried that because of the way that Google generates it's OpenID tokens it might accidentally create a new account for an existing user, giving them the impression the data in their original account has been lost.

As far as I can tell, Google will generate different claimed ID tokens for different domain names.  That is www.site.com and site.com would create two distinct tokens and therefore two accounts in my system. I've fixed that by redirecting www.site.com to site.com.

Are there any other gotchas I need to be aware of?  And can anyone point me in the direction of some details on what Google use to generate the ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the docs](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html#endpoint):

`openid.realm`

Authenticated realm. Identifies the domain that the end user is being asked to trust. (Example: "http://*.myexamplesite.com") This value must be consistent with the domain defined in openid.return_to. If this parameter is not defined, Google will use the URL referenced in `openid.return_to`.

The value of realm is used on the Google Federated Login page to identify the requesting site to the user. It is also used to determine the value of the persistent user ID returned by Google.

Comment: So by the URL, I'm assuming that includes the path, not just the domain?  That could explain it, as the return_to could be a deep link into the site...

Comment: And if I add the realm now, will it mess up existing IDs Google has generated?

Comment: Ok, digging through the django_openid_auth code, I can see it does set openid.realm correctly, to the root url of the site/domain.

Comment: You should read the section of the OpenID spec that applies to `openid.realm` for the precise details of this field: http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#realms

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow had the same problems with different hash OpenID tokens. They detail there problems and a possible solution (Google profiles) on [StackOverflow blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/).

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/google-offers-named-openids/

Comment: Profiles require the user to preemptively solve a problem they don't know they have, so I don't think that helps.